# the vertex covers in a bipartite graph

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Let $M$ be a matching of size $n$ between $S$ and $T$. We add some edges to $M$ between $S$ and $T$ to get a connected bipartite graph $G$ with sides $S$ and $T$.

And I am looking for the vertex cover of $G$ (that is a vertex subset of $G$ intersecting with each edge of $G$) of size $n$ and intersects each edge of $G$ at **one** vertex. Then $S$ and $T$ are. I am wondering is there any more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, $S$ and $T$ are the only vertex cover intersects with each edge at 1 vertex: suppose not, there is a cover having one vertex $s\in S$ and $t\in T$ and there is a path between $s$ and $t$ in the bipartite graph. We get a contradiction as the vertices on this path are alternatively in the vertex cover.

Answer (score 0):

Of course there are other vertex covers as well.
Take an arbitrary subset $X\subset S$. Let $Y=T-N_M(X)$.
The set $X\cup Y$ is a vertex cover $G$ of $n$ elements.

Comment: Sorry. There is one more restriction that the vertex cover intersects each edge at 1 vertex. (Somehow this sentence was gone after my editing)